# Transient Instance of a NSManagedObject

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

I want to create an instance of an `NSManagedObject` which should not be stored in the Core Data store immediately.

In some cases I want to store the instance later.

Is this possible (simple alloc/init of my `NSManagedObject` subclass is not allowed)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can I ask why you need to store the object later?

With the information given in your question I would just say: No, it is not possible because, as you say, you should always use the designated initializer of NSManagedObject

From documentation:

> NSManagedObject uses dynamic class generation to support the
>   Objective-C 2 properties feature (see “Declared Properties”) by
>   automatically creating a subclass of the class appropriate for
>   entity.initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext: therefore
>   returns an instance of the appropriate class for entity. The
>   dynamically-generated subclass will be based on the class specified by
>   the entity, so specifying a custom class in your model will supersede
>   the class passed to alloc.

Comment: Thanks, I want to show a ModalDialog to create an new object. Therefor want to use an instance of this object, which has some convinience-methods I need. If the user leaves the dialog with "cancel" I want to discard the instance without storing it. Only if the user says "store" the instance should be persisted.

Comment: I assume you need the object to be created when you show the ModalDialog. If that was not the case I would create the object when the user taps "Store" otherwise do nothing. If you need the object in your ModalDialog then yes it is best practice by calling deleteObject when the user taps "Cancel". That is how I would do it.

Comment: Actually, a way that could be possible to do it is to init your object without a context. In other words you call initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext: and pass in nil as the context. Then when the user taps "Store" you will call: [context insertObject:object]; then save the context when needed. This might work in your case because if the user taps "Cancel" the object will not be associated with a context and not being saved.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working for me. (I have the situation where I want to offer possible data which will never be stored to the db.)